# Why do Guillemin and Pollack avoid the term "submanifold with boundary"?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold, transversality

On p. 60 of the book *"Differential Topology"* by named authors they state:

> **Theorem.** Let $f$ be a smooth map of a manifold $X$ with boundary onto a boundaryless manifold $Y$, and suppose that both $f:X\to Y$ and
>   $\partial f:X\to Y$ are transversal with respect to a boundaryless
>   submanifold $Z$ in $Y$. Then the premiage $f^{-1}(Z)$ is a manifold
>   with boundary $$\partial\{f^{-1}(Z)\}=f^{-1}(Z)\cap \partial X$$ and
>   the codimension of $f^{-1}(Z)$ in $X$ equals the codimension of $Z$ in
>   $Y$.

Why don't they call $f^{-1}(Z)$ a *submanifold of $X$ with boundary*?

Would that be mathematically incorrect?

In the proof they show that around a boundary point, $f^{-1}(Z)$ is diffeomorphic to a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^k$ intersected with the halfspace $\mathbb{H}^k$ *under a chart for $X$*, so I do not see why you wouldn't be able to call $f^{-1}(Z)$ a submanifold of $X$.

Same thing on p. 62:

> **Lemma.** Suppose that S is a manifold without boundary and that $\pi:S\to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function with regular value $0$.
>   Then the subset $\{s\in S:\pi(s) \geq 0\}$ is a manifold with
>   boundary, and the boundary is $\pi^{-1}(0)$.

Why not call $\pi^{-1}(0)$ a *submanifold of $S$ with boundary*?

Comment: You'll have to ask them. But in my experience of writing mathematics, it's not always worthwhile to pick a name for every mathematical concept.